# Centos 7, Freezing a (root) file system before (xfs) dumping it

Tags: linux, centos

I have just installed Centos 7 on my comp. My setup has three partitions root (/), /data and /home. All partitions are of the xfs type.
Now I tried to do the backup of the root partition. In order to do that I executed:

```
xfsdump -l 0 -f /data/root_fs.xfs /
```

Everything went well.

Actually I was a bit confused that everything went well because I was dumping live mounted file system. In order to be sure that backup will be good, I decided to freeze the root file system, and then to dump it. To do so I have executed:

```
Xfs_freeze –f /;xfsdump -l 0 -f /dev/root_fs.xfs /;xfs_freeze –u /
```

…but now my system hangs. I can ping it, but I don't have access from the keyboard nor from ssh, so I have to do the hard reset.

The same procedure (prior freezing) I can use on let’s say /data or /home partitions with no problem at all.

My questions are:

1. Will xfsdump with no prior freezing of root file system, ended in partition backup that I will be able to use for bare bone recovery (let’s say on a new disk)?
2. Why I can freeze /data or /home file systems but not root file system?

Regards.

Comment: The manpage says: "Any process attempting to write to the frozen filesystem will block waiting for the filesystem to be unfrozen". As system processes use to write e.g. log files etc., they are blocked until your dump is done. You should not use `xfs_freeze` for long lasting operations; from the manpage: "xfs_freeze is intended to be used with volume managers and hardware RAID devices that support the creation of snapshots" - as snapshots only need parts of seconds to be created. And if your dump is usable depends on what files are modified during the dump.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but in case someone happens to have the same questions:

1. `xfsdump` is indeed designed to be run on live filesystems. Assuming you don't update binaries through the dump process, or move files around, the dump will be consistent and good for recovery. Try to have as quiet filesystem as possible.
2. As the comment to your question says, freezing for long time can create problems. The root filesystem is problematic since (depending on layout) it might include `/var` as well, which means logging hangs, updating `utmp` hangs, etc. so I'm not surprised you can't login anymore.